# Rails4 Bootstrap3 cannot find glyphicons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using google-webfonts-rails gem w Rails 4.1.6 / Bootstrap 3.1 ( don't know if it's a good choice...)

I tried to get rid of this error by adding fonts folders w glyph icons in many places ...

```
 app/assets/fonts/...
 app/assets/javascripts/fonts/...
 app/assets/stylesheets/fonts/...
```

and I still get this error in the console log :

```
Started GET "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 11:11:59 +0200
Processing by ApplicationController#routing_error as 
Parameters: {"path"=>"fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 7ms
```

it's still not very clear to me where I should add the fonts w Bootstrap3 ....

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right folder is :

```
 app/assets/bootstrap/...
```

moving my glyphicons into it , did the trick .. no more error in the console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working  .. odours gave me trick