# Bootstrap Glyphicons not working properly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

In my RoR application I've added to my search input a glyphicon inside my lateral button but this is the result:

[image: Icon not Rendered]

The icon is not renderized.

this is my code:

```
<div class="top-space"> <!--.top-space-->
<div class="row"> <!--.row-->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><!--.col-->
    <h1 class="text-center">Search a Project</h1>
        <%= form_tag find_path,:class => 'input-group' ,:method => 'post' do%>
            <%=text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'form-control'%>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary",) do %>
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              <% end %>
            </span>
        <% end %>
    </div> <!--.col-->
</div> <!--.row-->
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: how have you install bootstrap on ROR? are you using any gem?

Comment: Did you check the error log? It may be routing error like "No route matches [GET] "/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff""

Comment: Already answered : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working