# rails glyphicons not uploaded in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have trouble with uploading glyphicons in production in my rails 4 app.

Solutions like this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working) not working for me.

My application.css.scss file contain this lines:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
$icon-font-path: "bootstrap/";
```

It's right path on production to glyphicons fonts in `application.css` file, for example:

```
url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-8cd45fc682c0e3a2695ce9453750efec.woff2") format("woff2")
```

I try to download this file(mydomain.com/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-8cd45fc682c0e3a2695ce9453750efec.woff2) and I've downloaded it, that mean that files stores in servers in the right directory. And in my browser I don't see 404 errors.

But I noticed one thing, that confused me, locally I can see that glyphicons fonts downloaded:

[image]

And in production I don't see that file in network tab:

[image]

And there are no js errors

Why glyphicons doesn't load in production mode in rails?

Comment: Have you taken a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline , you may need to add the font file extensions to the precompile list.

Comment: @danielrsmith on server it stored precompiled fonts in directory my_app/public/assets/bootstrap and I can download it, my problem is that fonts don't uploaded font file in browser even with right path for fonts(with digest) in css rules and I don't know why.

Comment: Hmmm, normally I use https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass instead, since it make this process super easy and doesn't clog your repo with vendor code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downgraded `bootstrap-sass` gem from `3.3.5` to `3.3.0.1` and glyphicons work as expected.

**Updated:** update gem `'sass-rails', '>= 5.0.0'` correspond with this [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/927) and now glypicons works as expected with version of `bootstrap-sass` gem `3.3.5`