# undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, chartkick

Using `chartkick` with `wicked-pdf`.

app/layout/pdf.html.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8' />
 <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
 <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi"%>
 <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'chartkick'%>
 </head>
 <body onload='number_pages'>
 <div id="header">
  <h2>Report</h2>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

But it gives an error ON THIS LINE

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Error

```
  undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass
```

How I remove this?
Error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass):
2: <html>
3:   <head>
4:     <meta charset='utf-8' />
5:     <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
6:     <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
7:     <%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi"%>
8:     <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'chartkick'%>
 app/views/layouts/pdf.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_pdf_html_erb___3130978149028204091_70042742447040'
 app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in survey_reporting'
 app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:101:in `survey_reporting'
```

Comment: Can you post more of the stacktrace.

Comment: That error is telling you that you are calling start_with? on something which you expect to have a value but is actually equal to `nil`, possibly because it's an instance variable which you think you have defined but you actually haven't.  The stack trace will tell you specifically where this is happening.  Look for the first line which is in your project folder rather than a gem.

Comment: @j-dexx which file u need?

Comment: I update my question with some stacktrace

Comment: @HaseebAhmad What is in the `survey_reporting` method in the campaigns controller?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad - If you're seeing this error in your browser, please click "full stacktrace" and post what you'll get.

Comment: @HaseebAhmad - You didn't happen to override `WickedPdfHelper::Assets::ASSET_URL_REGEX` constant, did you? https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper/assets.rb#L21 Can't think of scenario that could return nil.

Comment: There is an official issue open for this problem: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/470

Comment: @BroiSatse what mean you didn't happen to override WickedPdfHelper::Assets::ASSET_URL_REGEX. I can't override anything like that

Comment: @HaseebAhmad - It's ruby, you can override everything here. :) That was rather a long shot though, so ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

Problem is resolved!

replace

`<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`

with `<%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("pdf") %>`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by creating a specif `pdf.css.scss` file and imported my custom style (`estilo.css`) and `font-awesome style`.

```
/*# pdf.css.scss 

@import "font-awesome";
@import "estilo";
```

I was unable to import the `bootstrap.css` file there because the `glyphicon`'s src-url method. It's broke `wicked_pdf`.

As a workaround, I simply copied all `bootstrap.css` files in my `pdf.css.scss` file and erased all about `glyphicon` since I'm not using it at all in my generated PDF.

---

---

### Update

Instead of coping and pasting all `bootstrap.css` source in your `pdf.css.scss` file, do this:

1. Follow these steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927496/2409274);
2. Add a line for you `bootstrap.css` file location in your `config/application.rb`. It should look like this:

   ```
   /*# config/application.rb

   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/" 
   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/" 
   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/fonts"
   ```
3. Finally add a import for bootstrap in your `pdf.css.scss` file. It should look like this:

   ```
   /*# pdf.css.scss

   @import "bootstrap";
   @import "font-awesome";
   @import "estilo";
   ```

By doing all this, `wicked_pdf` reading src-urls method will work!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` before `@import "bootstrap"`:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

check this [link](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/470#issuecomment-285386308)

Answer (score 1):

To handle this issue,
create a file app/assets/stylesheet/bootstrap.css
Then copy-paste the bootstrap css from any CDN.
Now include this file in the layout you are using.
ex: pdf.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PDF</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("bootstrap") %>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script at the controller side is like:

```
  def job_invoice_view

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'tukaweb' }
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "Your_filename",
               template: "users/job_invoice_view.html.erb",
               layout: 'pdf',
               viewport_size: '1280x1000'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. My problem was that my application.css.scss was including the [lightbox2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightbox2) npm package. The problem with this package is that assets paths seem to be broken in it which causes the arrows not to display. I guess the wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag doesn't ignore the fact that it can't find the asset like the normal stylesheet_link_tag does and causes the error. Creating a new css file specifically for the PDF and removing the lightbox2 reference fixed the error for us.