# Bootstrap icons not working in Rails 4 production environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this is a common issue and has been asked couple times here. I followed this method [Bootstrap 3+Rails 4 - Certain Glyphicons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working)
 it works in development and used to work in production but after working on my app in development and moving it to production it's stopped working anymore.I'm using Rails 4.2.5 on AWS ubuntu server. My assets were precompiled without errors.

Bootstrap files are placed in their appropriate directories in  myapp/app/assets. My icons and background image are not working in production only.I checked my log file it shows these errors.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]     "/stylesheets/bootstrap.css"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/bootstrap.js"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"):
```

etc

application.html.erb

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap"  %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

application.rb

```
 config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/app/assets/fonts"
 config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

bootstrap.css

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')       
    format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')     
    format('woff'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')    
    format('truetype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-    halflingsregular') format('svg');
```

application.css I renamed it to application.css.scss and still does not work. I'm not sure If I really need to rename it.

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
*= require_tree .
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.raty
//= require ratyrate
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Try this one: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I did it precompiled them with no errors. I added my bootstrap.css you may check that out it could be my issue :)

Comment: did u try to use gem bootstrap ?

Comment: I used to have it but I deleted it it because the syntax, do I have to change my current syntax If I install it now ?

Comment: if u dnt use gem then `//= require_tree .` should cover for you there. you dont need to include in application.js and .css files. try to remove them then restart the server.

Comment: also, dont forget to remove from application.html.erb file too.

Comment: just installed the gem still does not work but it changed my view. I removed require_tree still the icons did not appear.

Comment: I still do not know why I'm getting errors in my log

Comment: Try this gem:  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass , Remove everything from your `application.scss` and add this to it `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";`  `@import "bootstrap";`

Comment: Dnt remove require_tree . Remove bootstrap lines only  //= bootstrap in js and css file also from applicationhtml erb file

Comment: @7urkm3n from the gem documentation **remove all the `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree.` statements from the `sass` file. Instead, use `@import` to import `Sass files`.

Do not use `*= require` in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables.**

Comment: I get this now even though files exist   Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
Load paths:
  /home/ubuntu/senior-project/homeFoods/app/assets/fonts  etc

Comment: @dkp He mentioned didnt use `gem bootstrap`, its just copied bootstrap files.

Comment: @7urkm3n yes, i was suggesting to use sass bootstrap. I find it a better way of using bootstrap in a rails app. :)

Comment: Started GET "/homeFoods/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2" I see now this does not make sense why it's not getting the correct path ?