# Specify the correct path in assets pipeline Rails 4+

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I compiled my assets without errors they work in development environment without problems but they all broke in production. I checked my log file it seems that it's not referencing the correct location. This is one of the errors.

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/homeFoods/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2" for 132.241.174.123 
at 2016-04-08 22:35:59 +0000 F, [2016-04-08T22:35:59.294695 #26882] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"):

actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
passenger (5.0.24)   src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
 passenger (5.0.24)   
  src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'     passenger(5.0.24)src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'passenger(5.0.24) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads' passenger(5.0.24) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Why it's assuming that fonts directory is located under homeFoods not /homeFoods/app/assets/ ?

application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

bootstrap.css

```
font-face {
 font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
 src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') 
format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');}
```

I did try this approach [Bootstrap 3+Rails 4 - Certain Glyphicons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working) which used to work but not anymore.I do not know why it was working because the path he's specifying is not correct, vendor does not contain fonts folder.

```
   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
```

Comment: Helpful to see the console error when the page loads.

Comment: The error I mentioned is the problem. It does not show my icons when page is loaded !

Comment: Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I just create a new file `icons.css.scss` and use `asset-url` helper inside. For example:

`@font-face {
    font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
    src: asset-url('fontello.eot');
    src: asset-url('fontello.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        asset-url('fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
        asset-url('fontello.woff') format('woff'),
        asset-url('fontello.svg#EntypoRegular') format('svg');
}`

Next I include this file in my `application.css.scss` by adding `//= require icons`. Hope this help.