# Do not display several Glyphicons icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

Rails 4, Bootstrap 3
Do not display complicated  Glyphicons icons

displayed(this and other elementary):

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
```

not displayed(This and all which need complex rendering):

```
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i>
```

With what it can be connected?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working) SO Q&A which seems related to your issue. TL;DR: add `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` and `@import "bootstrap"` to your `application.css` file

Comment: @ davideghz It did not help anything written there.
added ` @import "bootstrap-sprockets" and @import "bootstrap"`

Comment: have you restarted your web server after adding the two @imports? Just to be sure: did you add `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` and `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'` to your Gemfile?